# ubuntu 9 index corrupted

Tags: ubuntu, corruption

I upgraded to Ubuntu 9 and I am now getting this error:

```
Tracker applet
There was an error while performing indexing
Index corrupted.
```

I've tried re-indexing, but the problem still shows up. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following two bugs:

- [Corrupted tracker index causes persistent applet error popup](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tracker/+bug/361560)
- [Tracker index corruption (was Tracker does not stop indexing)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tracker/+bug/346912)

A couple of potential solutions from those threads (for the person I was trying to help, the second solution worked better, since she was non-technical and got confused when trying to do the first):

> ```
> sudo apt-get install tracker-utils
> tracker-processes -r
> ```
>
> Then I logged out and back in so the
>   processes that I had previously killed
>   by hand would restart in a normal
>   fashion.

Or:

> - unchecking 'Enable indexing' in System->Preferences->Search & indexing
>     should be sufficient to stop trackerd,
>     at least after restarting your session
>     if it's hanging

Answer (score 0):

You could try re-installing tracker? Something like:

```
$ sudo apt-get uninstall tracker
$ sudo apt-get install tracker
```

(Or can you do a `reinstall`?)